# Entity Framework 5 and Code first - unable to add record to a table that has relation with other table(s)

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC4` application using `EF 5` and Code First workflow. I have two entities:

```
public class Document
{
  //other properties...
  public int DocumentID { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<UploadedFile> UploadedFiles { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class UploadedFile
{
  //other properties..
  public int UploadedFileID { get; set; }
  public int DocumentID { get; set; }
  public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

In short - I have different kind of documents and each document may have 1 or more files associated with him. What I haven't thought about is that I'm going to have files that are not associated with a document. So I still need to save the file specific information and the `UploadedFile` entity has all the properties I need for that but I don't want to set values for the `Document` properties (leave them null). Which leads to the problem.

I already have some business logic written and if I change to `public int? DocumentID { get; set; }` - make the FK nullable I get compile errors from the code that I already have. Also, I might to decide and rewrite my code to reflect that change but I'm not sure if setting the FK to be nullable is best solution anyways.

The second solution that I can think of is to just create another entity `OtherFiles` (or something like this, just example name) where I will keep the records for the files that are not associated with some kind of document. Which will solve my problem in general but it seems like the worst solution since I'm gonna repeat all the properties of `UploadedFile` but without the relation to another table.

And third - if anyways I have to rewrite my code in order to keep some decent design (which I am trying to do) maybe there's a better way than setting the FK to null. I've watched a part of video tutorial by Scott Allen where he was setting two entities with the same structure, there it was `Restaurant` and `RestaurantsReviews` and in this video he didn't bother at all adding `public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set;}` and had only `public int RestaurantID { get; set; }` saying that this is not mandatory but might be useful in some cases.

I don't know which cases are those, but maybe for my case it would be best just to remove `DocumentID` and `virtual Document Document` and rewrite my code? If this is the case what I lose as ability when I remove `DocumentID` from my `UploadedFile` entity?

Comment: Having the Id column and the virtual object to define the FK, helps when using lazy loading, and in many other ways. Imagine that you have the `RestaurantReview` and need the Restaurant's name, so you just access it trough the virtual object and don't need to write and you save some code lines and time. On the other hand you can't delete `DocumentId`, because EF is going to think you want to delete the FK and that's bad. You have a very complicated problem, so maybe you need a complicated solution. Continue..

Comment: Although I don't know how much code do you have, the first solution may be a good one if you use VS tools like search and replace and stuffs like that. It's not like you're gonna spend an entire week doing it, but of course you need to be sure if that's what you want, and when you finish it, you're gonna have a cleaner code and database structure.

Comment: @Guillelon Thanks for the detailed explanation.I'm not sure about the nullable types because I'm using Repositories and I'm using an example from codeplex or other respectable site (I don't remember anymore) and one of the first errors that I get is from the Generic repository where everything is using non nullable types (long). I already have some experience with `EF 5` but still don't know what are, if there are any pros and cons into using or not using nullable types in this case. If it wasn't for that I would probably change this without giving much of a thought. How do you think?

Comment: Also, post ti as answer if you want. It seems legit to me.

Comment: if that's how deep your code is right know, indeed is bad idea to change the FK to `int?`. Maybe the second solution ain't that bad at all, as I said you've a very complicated problem that may need a complicated solution. I used this generic repositories in the past but I really can't tell how can it affect you if you change the FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the Id column and the virtual object to define the FK, **helps when using lazy loading**, and in many other ways. So if you have something like this:

```
public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<RestaurantReviews> Reviews{ get; set; } 
}

public class RestaurantReviews
{
    public int Id{ get; set;}
    public string Review { get; set; }
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; } 
}
```

And for some reason you're working with the any `Review` and need the Restaurant's name, you just say:

```
var restaurantNameToShow = myReview.Restaurant.Name;
```

So `EF` is going to go again to the DB and get you the name (because he's lazy and didn't bring it in the first place). This answer your doubt about EF, regarding what option you should take, it's seems to me that is a very very complicated thing, and maybe a complicated solution ain't bad at all. For all the thing we spoke in the comments I'd choose the second option. If for some reason I get another idea on how solve it, I'm gonna tell it to you ;)